# Constraints in Julia

Tags: arrays, indexing, constraints, julia, julia-jump

I'm switching from AMPL to Julia right now, and while I've checked the JuMP manual on constraints, I didn't see there an answer to my question (in case I've missed it - I'm sorry :))

If I have a variable representing a production:

```
g[i,j]
```

Where i - is the number of possible producers and j - is the number of months. And a constant representing a total demand for each month:

```
d[j]
```

How should I construct my constraint, if I want the model to fulfill monthly demand? Right now I have this, but it doesn't seem to work for me:

```
for j in 1:6
    @constraint(model,sum(g[i,j] for i in 1:50) == d[j])
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to look at JuMP's documentation about constraint containers [here](http://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/v0.19.0/constraints/#Constraint-containers-1).

```
@constraint(model, myConstraintName[j=1:6], sum(g[i,j] for i in 1:50) == d[j])
```